# Write captured data to Excel using java

Tags: java

In my below script, an Excel is created but failed to write the data to the sheet. Could anybody sort this out.

```
FileOutputStream fo = new FileOutputStream("D:\\Output.xls");
WritableWorkbook wb = Workbook.createWorkbook(fo);
WritableSheet ws = wb.createSheet("Sheet1",0);
String OutText = driver.findElement(By.xpath("gbqfqdss")).getText();
int y=0;  
Label label1 = new Label(0,y,OutText);
 ws.addCell(label1);
Thread.sleep(1000);
 //System.out.print(OutText);
 wb.write();
 y++;
Thread.sleep(1000);
driver.findElement(By.id("gbqfq")).clear();
Thread.sleep(1000);
}
 wb.close();
driver.quit();
```

Comment: How is this related to either eclipse or selenium?

Comment: You aren't closing WritableSheet (can it be closed?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the same code, working fine in my lappy.

How you are confirming that it is not writing to excel sheet?

Mostly the cause should be "OutText" string value  which is coming from getText() is null/blank value.

Try to print the value of string first & see.

Comment: The return value of OutText is Integer, I declared here as String. But the data type of gettext is String! Could you guide me how to modify my code to return an Integer value

Comment: Are you looking for [`Integer.parseInt()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt%28java.lang.String%29)?

Comment: getText() method always returns String value only...  And as of i know u can write only string values to Excel with JXL libraries. Better after writing to excel convert the OutText value to integer using Integer.paseInt() method.

Comment: Thank you everyone for your time. I could not resolve it since I have prob in my xpath. OutText returns null. I used Integer.parseInt() as well. But its not working.

Comment: If the getText method is returning null,  Parseint can do nothing.  First correct the XPATH.  Then code will work fine. And if returning null is the problem,  please accept the answer,  so that everyone knows the answer.

Comment: Actually the element is located inside a frame and now I modified my code. But now, its writing only the first value of iteration to excel. I need to write more data to excel but it stuck off at "Label label1 = new Label(0,y,OutText);" Could anybody sort this out please.

Comment: Where is your loop in the code mentioned in the question.... First update the question with proper code.... I think you are defining y = 0 within the loop. Check that once.

Answer (score 0):

Try the examples in the following link-:

http://howtodoinjava.com/2013/06/19/readingwriting-excel-files-in-java-poi-tutorial/